# Container not expanding with content

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of a problem with one of my containers. It is not expanding with my content. Here is the code:

```
<!--center section start-->
<div id="centerContent">
    <!--center left begin-->
    <div id="centerLeft">
    <h2>
    Special Disney Ticket Offer!
    </h2>
    <p class="specCont">
    <img class="specImg" src="images/universal-main-offer.jpg" alt="Special Universal Studios Ticket Offer!" />
    Super Value Disney 3 Day Touch of Magic Ticket! Just $219 for each ticket! Get 3 Days to visit the Disney Theme Parks (Magic Kingdom,        Epcot, Hollywood Studios, Animal Kingdom) PLUS a 4th day at Disney Quest, Blizzard Beach or Typhoon Lagoon! For an unbelievable value!        Call &amp; ask for the Resort offer<br />(restrictions apply).<br /> <strong>Call us: 1-800-544-7646</strong>
    </p>
    </div>
    <!--center left end-->
    <!--center right begin-->
    <div id="centerRight">
    <a href="http://tix.greatorlandodiscounts.com/index.php?catid=106">
    <img class="rightFrontImg" src="images/legoland-fl-front-ad.jpg" alt="Legoland Florida Discount Tickets" />
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--center right end-->
</div>
<!--center section end-->
```

CSS:

```
#centerContent {
    width: 980px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url(../images/main-special-bg-strip.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#centerLeft {
    width: 572px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

#centerRight {
    width: 408px;
    height: 100%;
    float:right;
}
```

What I am looking to do is have the centerContent div stretch with the two divs inside. I have a background strip on the centerContent that will allow the white background to expand 100%.

I hope that made some sort of sense and thank you in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto;` to `#centerContent`.

Since the child divs are floated, the parent collapses and acts like it has no content. Adding `overflow:auto;` restores the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I just tried that and I got scroll bars on the bottom and on the right.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, that doesn't happen: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KW6M9/. You could also try `overflow:hidden` instead.

Comment: Thank you, again. I tried that and I get the same effect as before. Is there any away that I can post the entire page code?